# How to delete an iOS app from iTunes Connect after the account has expired

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

My client had an iTunes Dev account for their app and for some reason they wanted the new version of the app under a new account. They created the new account but let the old account expire.

The old app needs to be deleted before the same name can be used in the new account.
iTunes Connect is not letting us do that!!
The app has been removed from sale from all territories. The status of the app is 'Pending Contract' and the delete button doesn't appear.

If someone can guide us to the right place (in the portal) to raise such issue with Apple or some way by which we can sort this out ourselves, it'll be helpful.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what happened in the end.
After several back and forth calls with Apple to solve this issue (which included verifying the reason for such request and the validation of ownership of both the accounts by same person/company) Apple re-activated the old developer account for a period 10 days, during which time any changes can be made in that account, including deletion of the old app (thereby freeing up that name for use in another account). They also warned that such extension will not be given in future for any reason.

Hope this helps others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You client may have to renew the old developer account in order to make **any** changes.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. i really hope that's not the case!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution would been to transfer the App to the new account:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

You would have kept all the information and history.

Comment: Thanks, Rivera. Fortunately they have introduced this option now and has made life simpler for businesses and developers. This option wasn't available at that time and hence the complication.